# awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception (sample code)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Ok I'm getting this error awt eventqueue 0 nullpointerexception error. When I try to remove a JPanel.

Whats confusing me is when I click on the price button, it removes the time JPanel. It works perfectly fine but for the one when i click on the timebutton, it doesn't remove the pricepanel, instead i get an awt eventqueue error. The first Code below shows my main class, a time class and a price class.   Sorry I reposted i wanted to post my code. 
Below is a sample of code

```
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public class events extends JFrame {
   // variables for JPanel


  private JButton timeButton;
  private JButton priceButton;

       setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

  buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
  buttonPanel.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Main Menu"));


         timeButton = new JButton("Time"); 
  buttonPanel.add(timeButton);

  priceButton = new JButton("Price");
  buttonPanel.add(priceButton);




           buttontime clickTime = new buttontime(); // event created when time button is clicked
  timeButton.addActionListener(clickTime);


         //ActionListener created for price
   buttonprice ClickPrice = new buttonprice(); // event created when price button is clicked
   priceButton.addActionListener(ClickPrice);


         public class buttontime implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime) {
    Price priceObject = new Price();
    priceObject.getPricepanel();
    remove(priceObject.getPricepanel());
    priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();

    add(timeObject.getTimePanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();

   }
}

      //This one gives me 0 errors.
           public class buttonprice implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on      timebutton to bring up a combobox

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ClickPrice) {
    Price priceObject = new Price();
    priceObject.SelectPrice();
    remove(timeObject.getTimePanel());
    timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();

    add(priceObject.getPricepanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();
```

}
}

```
         TIME CLASS

             class Time
 {

   private JComboBox    timeAirportbox;//comboboxes declared

     private String[] airport = {"","East Midlands", "Birmingham", "Manchester", "Heathrow"};//array of    airports declared
    private String[] destination = {"","New York", "Dahab", "Rome", "Sydney", "Tokyo"};//array of destinations declared
 private JPanel timePanel;
 private JLabel airportLabel;  
  private JLabel destinationLabel;
 public void SelectTime() {   

 //combobox objects created
      timePanel = new JPanel();
  timePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

      timePanel.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Time"));
  timeAirportbox = new JComboBox(airport);//array is inserted into the JComboBox
  timePanel.add(timeAirportbox);
  timeAirportbox.setVisible(true);

}
   public JPanel getTimePanel() {
    return timePanel;
    }

     public JComboBox getAirportBox() {
    return timeAirportbox;      
    }


    }

            PRICE CLASS


                class Price {

     private JPanel pricePanel;
      private JLabel tester;

    public void SelectPrice() {
    pricePanel = new JPanel();
  pricePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  pricePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
  tester = new JLabel("HIFHI");
  pricePanel.add(tester);

  }

   public JPanel getPricepanel() {
    return pricePanel;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your example doesn't declare nor initialize the `timeObject` or `priceObject`.  I don't see the point of passing `buttonPanel` to the constructor if all you are going to do is reassign it

Comment: please don't open a new question with the exact same problem, instead edit the first to include the relevant details :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have an endless list of issues and problems.

The two immediate are...

In you you `Price` class, you never initialise `pricePanel`....

```
class Price {

    private JPanel pricePanel;
    private JLabel tester;

    public void SelectPrice() {
        pricePanel = new JPanel();
        pricePanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        tester = new JLabel("HIFHI");
        pricePanel.add(tester);

    }

    public JPanel getPricepanel() {
        return pricePanel;
    }
}
```

This is what's causing your `NullPointerException`.

The second problem you will face is the fact that you creating local copies of the `PriceObject`, but are some how expecting to be able to remove the panel that the previously instantiated object added

```
public class buttontime implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime) {
        Price priceObject = new Price();
        priceObject.getPricepanel();
//----> Remove a local reference of price panel <---- //       
        remove(priceObject.getPricepanel());
        priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();

        add(timeObject.getTimePanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();

    }
}

//This one gives me 0 errors.
public class buttonprice implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on      timebutton to bring up a combobox

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ClickPrice) {
        Price priceObject = new Price();
        priceObject.SelectPrice();
        remove(timeObject.getTimePanel());
        timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate();

//----> Adding a local reference of price panel <---- //       
        add(priceObject.getPricepanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        priceObject.getPricepanel().revalidate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for the help im not giving up yet. what do you mean by local references?

Comment: Each method creates an instance of `Price` and then tries to either add or remove it's panel.  Adding is fine, but the remove won't work, as the value of the panel is not the same as the one that was added

Comment: so i wont be able to solve it ?

Comment: Sure, not create a local reference in the method.  You need to maintain a class level reference to the "current" price object.  When you need to remove the panel, use this reference (if it's not `null`).  When you need to add a new one, create a new instance and assign it to the class level reference

Comment: _setPreferredSize_ ?? Boooooohhhhh ... don't show worst-practices to newbies, in the end those tend to be the only thingies they remember :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Actually, I didn't, that was part of there original code - there was so much else wrong that I simply copied and pasted there code, my bad

Comment: @MadProgrammer missed that in all the noise of OP's code, sorry, should have known better :-)